# Second monitor flickering and leaving trail with black background in extended display on Manjaro GNOME/Wayland

Tags: linux, gnome, wayland

I am running the latest version of GNOME and Wayland on my Manjaro computer. When I connect my second monitor and extend my display, one screen flickers and the mouse icon leaves a trail, with a black background. However, I can still open applications and drag them to the second screen, which works fine. Mirror mode for two screens works great. What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it?

After trying some more things, it seems everything except the background is working, the bottom bar is working, when i press super key it will take me to menu where I can move.

When I try to screenshot the buggy monitor it just screenshots the normal background. (The background picture)

I tried updating GNOME and Wayland, also tried to update the whole system with pacman -Syu to no avail. Tried looking it up but couldn't find anything.

Comment: to me this sounds like a graphics driver issue, either that or its the hardware, how old is the hardware? Are you using nvidia, amd, or intel? nvidia is known to have problems with Gnome, have you tried X11 at all?

Comment: It worked fine like month ago, it just started one day, my hardware is relatively new, I am using AMD and no I didn't try X11.

Comment: I would say that you should try X11, if that doesnt work, check Gnome logs, usually located at /var/log/syslog, you can change to X11 by editing /etc/gdm/custom.conf and change add WaylandEnable=false

Comment: Thank you for a tip, I am kinda hesitant because until now I really liked Wayland.